# Why doesn't this anchor href work in Firefox?

Tags: asp.net, html

Here is the code:

```
<a href="http:\\www.drdanialbari.com" target="_blank"> Preview </a>
```

It works in Internet Explorer, not in Firefox.  Firefox adds a prefix in the link and takes the visitor to 'http://www.albariogroup.net/\www.drdanialbari.com'which gives Error 404.  It seems to be adding the parent web URL as a prefix.

It should jump directly to `http:\\www.drdanialbari.com` as IE does.

Comment: Is it possible that it's because you used "obliques" (backslashes) instead of forward slashes in the URL? I.e. it should be `http://`.

Answer (score 4):

```
<a href="http:\\www.drdanialbari.com" target="_blank"> Preview </a>
```

should be

```
<a href="http://www.drdanialbari.com" target="_blank"> Preview </a>
```